# Best Way to Develop Mobile Browser Games

Tags: user-interface, design-patterns, mobile, methods, logic

I want to ask this because I want to know developer perspective about developing from scratch mobile games.

Let's say the project is already going to start its development.
I am already aware of the specification of the project example.
Logic, Browser/devices to support, IDE to be used.

What should be the first thing to do.

- Create the UI/UX designs for all devices with no functionality 
  and after the designs are finalized then integrate functionality
- Create functionality logic then do design
- Do design and functionality together

which of these will save much more time.

please share your experiences about this development and how to make out of it
so that failure of delivering the project will be at its minimum errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every of these aproaches may work, however I will tell you about my experience.

I did a lot of different projects using points you provide in the question, but for me the easiest and most successful approach was **logic first, design second**.

How to start using this approach?

1. Think about **use case** at first. For example, user should be able to register in the game.
2. Implement **database** structure(if needed). For example, create table 'Users'.
3. Implement **data access logic**. For example, write code that saves a username and a password.
4. Create service layer with **use case's (business) logic implementation** . For example, you can write `saveUser` method.
5. Create a **simple(ugly) UI** that allows you to feel the use case and to test it.
6. Pay guru designer to **create clean design**. For example, a design of the registration page.
7. **Сontinue** with step 1.

Advantages?

- Allows to create really working [MVP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_viable_product) with ease.
- UI manipulates only real and dynamic data.
- Allows you to build foundation first.